# Trouble displaying data from MongoDb by using js/express.js,

Tags: javascript, mongodb, display, frontpage

I have a hard time displaying data from my MongoDB to my frontpage. I can see that I get the right number of items in my collection but it tells me [object Object] when I try to display the chosen data. Can anyone help? Thank you
[Code for getting data from the collection "title"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUT54.png)

[Call for displaying the 1 element in the title array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVLcx.png)

[What the browser tells me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0NSI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to display a whole object which results in `[object Object]`. You have to give your HTML a string like `result[0].title` (assuming you have a field `title` in your object)

You can also display the whole object with `JSON.stringify(result[0])` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I thought I had tried that but nope. Now it works:) Have a good day